# How to extract month from date time feild?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a model with nulluble createdDate field. I want to extract month from that created date feild. Here is my code in controller method. I think the problem is in LINQ query. Can you please help me to correct that query? Now reslts for that query is null.

```
 public JsonResult GetDispatchNoteByMonth(string month)
        {
            IEnumerable<Domain.DispatchNote.DispatchNote> dispatchNotes = _dispatchNoteService.GetAllDispatchNote().Where(d => d.Status == "Open" && d.CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().Month.ToString().Contains(month));
            IEnumerable<DispatchNoteViewModel> models = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DispatchNoteViewModel>>(dispatchNotes);

            if(models.Count() > 0)
            {
                return Json(new { IsDataAvailable = true, DispatchNotes = models }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { IsDataAvailable = false, Message = "No Dispatch notes found" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

I pass month value by selecting dropdown value. Here is my Javascript code,

$("#monthDropdown").change(function () {
    $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
    $('#openDispatchNoteTable .tbtr').after('');
    //$('#spinnerContainer').jmspinner();

```
var selectedValue = $("#monthDropdown").val();

if(selectedValue != ""){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Dispatch/GetDispatchNoteByMonth?month=" + selectedValue,
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#openDispatchNoteTable').find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
            $('#spinnerContainer').jmspinner(false);
            if (response.IsDataAvailable) {
                $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
                for (var i = 0 ; i <= response.DispatchNotes.length ; i++){
                    if (response.DispatchNotes[i].CreatedDate != null) {
                        $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
                        $('#openDispatchNoteTable .tbtr').after('<tr><td> <input type="checkbox" class="dispatchNotesToInvoiceCb" name="dispatchNotesToInvoice" value="' + response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchNoteId + '" /></td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchId + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].Client + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].CompanyAddress + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].Quantity + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].Driver + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].VehicleLicensePlateNumber + '</td><td>' + moment(new Date(parseInt(response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchDate.substr(6))).toLocaleDateString()).format('YYYY-MMMM-DD') + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].CreatedUser + '</td><td>' + moment(new Date(parseInt(response.DispatchNotes[i].CreatedDate.substr(6))).toLocaleDateString()).format('YYYY-MMMM-DD') + '</td><td><a class="editbtn btn btn-default btn-raised" href="/Dispatch/ClosedCancelledView/' + response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchNoteId + '">View<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></td></tr>');
                    } else {
                        $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
                        $('#openDispatchNoteTable .tbtr').after('<tr><td> <input type="checkbox" class="dispatchNotesToInvoiceCb" name="dispatchNotesToInvoice" value="' + response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchNoteId + '" /></td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchId + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].Client + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].CompanyAddress + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].Quantity + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].Driver + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].VehicleLicensePlateNumber + '</td><td>' + moment(new Date(parseInt(response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchDate.substr(6))).toLocaleDateString()).format('YYYY-MMMM-DD') + '</td><td>' + response.DispatchNotes[i].CreatedUser + '</td><td></td><td><a class="editbtn btn btn-default btn-raised" href="/Dispatch/ClosedCancelledView/' + response.DispatchNotes[i].DispatchNoteId + '">View<div class="ripple-container"></div></a></td></tr>');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $('#checkAll').prop('disabled', true);
                $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
                $('#openDispatchNoteTable .tbtr').after('<tr><td colspan="11" align="center" style="color:red">' + response.Message + ' ' + $("#monthDropdown option:selected").text() + '</td></tr>');
            }
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            console.log(reponse);
            $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
            $('#spinnerContainer').jmspinner(false);
            $('#openDispatchNoteTable .tbtr').after('<tr><td colspan="11" align="center" style="color:red">Error occured while fetching dispatch notes. Please try again.</td></tr>');
        }
    })
}
else {
    $('.tbtr').nextAll('tr').remove();
    $('#spinnerContainer').jmspinner(false);
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

> DateTime.Month method returns an integer that is 1-based: January is
>   equal to 1, and December is equal to 12.

In your case you should check which format month variable is holding. If your month format is "MMM" (i.e "jan") then you need to convert the CreatedDate field date

```
d.CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().Month.ToString("MMMM") 




IEnumerable<Domain.DispatchNote.DispatchNote> dispatchNotes = _dispatchNoteService.GetAllDispatchNote().Where(d => d.Status == "Open" && d.CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().Month.ToString("MMMM").ToLower().Contains(month).ToLower());
```

Comment: I checked the date format by using the method that you are proposing. Then what should i do. Can you please tell me.

Comment: Here is my new query,               IEnumerable<Domain.DispatchNote.DispatchNote> dispatchNotes = _dispatchNoteService.GetAllDispatchNote().Where(d => d.Status == "Open" && d.CreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().Month.ToString("MMMM").Contains(month));
                IEnumerable<DispatchNoteViewModel> models = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DispatchNoteViewModel>>(dispatchNotes);

Comment: I checked the updated answer and edited my code. but its not work. dispatchNotes variable will be empty result. what's happening?

Comment: can you post sample data that you recieved using GetAllDispatchNote()

Comment: 00171 Richard Pieris - Colombo Colombo 6 yol - G AAA-1111 2018-November-14  Akalanka Dissanayaka  2018-November-14 3:42:38 PM

Comment: Those are the sample data.

Comment: Last date that means 2018-November-14 3:42:38 PM is the created date. from that date i want to extract month by using the query that i mention. that query is in controller method.